# How to create a .d.ts file for an internal JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-intellisense

I have a JavaScript project which uses a json file for configuration.  Which config file is loaded is determined by environment variables, so I have a wrapper file, `config.js` that loads the proper json file and exports it as a constant.

I'm using VS Code, and would like to create a declaration file so I can get intellisense.  I'm not familiar enough with TypeScript to know the correct file structure nor how to associate my config.js file with the exported interface (or module or namespace?).

This is a dumbed down version of what I have.  As far as I can tell, VS Code doesn't know to associate `config.d.ts` with the export of `config.js`.

**/config/config.json**

```json
{
    "setting1": {
        "prop1": "foo",
        "prop2": 123
    },
    "setting2": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

**/src/config.js**

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join('..', 'config', 'config.json')));

// do some stuff to `config`

export default config;
```

**/src/config.d.ts**

```ts
export namespace config {
    export const setting1: {
            prop1: string,
            prop2: number
        },
        setting2: string[]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config.d.ts` should look like this to match the structure of `config.js`:

```
const config: {
    setting1: {
        prop1: string,
        prop2: number
    },
    setting2: string[]
};
export default config;
```

Note that the `config` constant is declared with a type that matches the structure of your configuration file, and the `export default` part is identical.  Having the `config.d.ts` file in the same directory as `config.js` should be enough for TypeScript to find it.  If this isn't working, please add the exact error that you get to the question.